# Can't Figure out the adjective declension

Tags: article

In the Sentence

> Auf dieser Reise bin ich nicht allein

`Auf dieser Reise` is in Nominative form and Reise is Feminine

but declension of dieser suggests it's in either Dative or Genitive.

Am I missing something?

Comment: It's not a nominative. "Auf" requires use of the dative here.

Answer (score 2):

You are right that “dieser Reise” is dative or genitive. The preposition “auf” goes with dative or accusative, so it must be dative.

Maybe you think that the first part of a sentence must always contain a nominative, but that’s not true. The subject is clearly “ich” which matches the verb “bin”, and “ich” is nominative as the subject has to be.

In German, the subject doesn’t need to be first. It is only required that the verb is second, and it is because “auf die Reise” counts as one part.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that with flexible word order in German, the subject does not have to come before the verb as in English. The word for word translation is Yodaesque: "On this trip am I not alone." I promise it's very natural sounding in German though.

Answer (score 0):

It has already been suggested (@CarstenS.) that the word order may be a problem, so I won't repeat it.

> Am I missing something?

First of all, the title speaks of "Adjective" and you forgot to mention it in the text of the question.

Second, you might not be aware of "auf reisen" as an idiom. You'll notice that it contains no case information.

There appears to be the plural noun *Reisen*, which may license use of the singular form *Reise*. Other than that, the phrase appears like a participle, which is historically difficult and doesn't license a singular: compare *beim Kochen*, also *im Gehen, en passant, on tour*. For difficult univerbations it's difficult to rule out a by-form in the above, like from **jabai* conj. "when": compare *ob*, English *if*, etc. As for *im Gehen*, not *Gang*, there's a counter example: *aus vollem Lauf* (of guns, metaphorically), *in vollem Lauf* (literally) respectively *im Laufen*. Whether *voll* is parsed as an adjective or an adverb is crucial, but the phrase as a whole is adverbial. As for *on tour*, it may be notable that *entourage* embodies the idea of "Auf dieser Reise bin ich nicht allein".

Since German barely recognizes adverbs as an *inflectional* category with adverbial participles, parsing an "Adjective" seems to be preferred in that case. Its inflection is marked and it works as deictic determiner. Out of context, our example has the determiner appear deictic as well. This alone makes it an article.

That aside, *dieser* may be an article but it is really a locative determiner, though not anymore since the "The locative case had merged into the dative case" (WP). It's a bit like English *this'ere*. But see also the placename *Rothenburg ob der Tauber*.

This may be of substantial age. Therefore it should be no real surprise that it is thoroughly grammaticalized.